# How to say "Goodbye forever"

Tags: vocabulary, translation, word-usage

How do you say , "goodbye forever" to someone? In sort of TV playful dramatic tone?

Example: You're boyfriend/girlfriend  is leaving the country, or someone you won't see ever again.

Is it this? 영원히 안녕

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're asking something like Adieu or Adios.
I haven't heard of saying 영원히 안녕 though.
Alternatively people says:

1. 잘 가 (or 안녕) (It still means goodbye, but it may mean adieu depending on the context.)
2. 잘 지내 (or 잘 살아) (means 'I wish you live well')
3. 행복해 (or 행복하게 살아) (means 'I wish you live happily')

There may be some others too.

---

If you really mean to say 'goodbye forever', you may say:

1. 영영 안녕 (means goodbye forever)
2. 이젠 안녕 (means goodbye (forever) now)

Comment: @mattsmith5 Koreans never say "goodbye forever". They just say bye or goodbye in such situations you mentioned. They may say it with slightly different tone. Anyway depending on the situation or the context, the same 'goobye' or 'bye' may mean 'goodbye forever'. Or you may say alternatively as I listed above.

Comment: interesting, google translate and papago say "영영 안녕" means goodbye everyone, however those translators can be incorrect

Comment: @mattsmith5 Considering that "영영 안녕" is rarely used in Korean, the mistranslation probably happened because you didn't specify an audience: the translator translated "영영 안녕" as bye and then added a random audience (Everyone).
Additionally, the reason Korean don't say '영원히 안녕' is most likely because '안녕' in Korean is a momentary greeting. On the other hand, '지내' is continuous, so a sentence like '안녕, 잘 지내' is more appropriate.

Comment: @user_A The reason why Koreans don't say "영원히 안녕" is probably same to why Americans don't say " Goodbye forever" (do they say that?). I think that Koreans don't say "영원히 안녕", because if they do it would sounds like a curse (i.e. I'll never see you again). They sometimes say "이제 못 보겠네" (we may not be able to see again), which is a quite different meaning, i.e. it actually implies "(I hope to see you again if I can but,) we may not be able to see again". It's very different from "I will never see you again".

Comment: They may say "이젠 다시 보지 말자" (Let's not see again) or "너 다시는 안볼거야" (I'll never see you again), but those are all bad meanings. Someone might say that "영원히 안녕" is neutral and doesn't reflect the person's will, but I think that it reflects the person's will (i.e. the person intends to not see again somehow) to a certain degree, because otherwise how he/she knows if they will bump into each other in the future?

Comment: @KayK. First of all, I think it's inappropriate to distinguish nuances without context, especially in a Q&A like this. And in my opinion, the source of this confusion is that "영원히 안녕" is a translation of "goodbye forever", which was not originally used in Korean.
To think about what you say, I don't think "영원히 안녕" carries the connotation of a curse. I think Korean speakers use "영원히 안녕" when they are unable to be reunited with the listener more.

Comment: This may be confusing because "영원히 안녕" is rarely used. It's a slightly different situation, but the "영영 이별" is obviously used when the speaker is regretting an unavoidable separation. I'm attaching links to poems and song lyrics that use "영원히 안녕" and "영영 이별". https://samuellove.tistory.com/421 https://music.bugs.co.kr/track/2430848

Comment: @user_A I am not sure if you noticed but the poem is about a man who just committed suicide. And his last word was the "영원히 안녕". It is not the same situation that the OP was talking about.

Comment: You may see those expressions like "영원히 안녕" or "영영 이별" in some poems or lyrics (or maybe in some old movies), but you may not hear people say those in a real life, which was my point.

Comment: yeah, i was looking for a more playful dramatic tv tone, updated question

Comment: yeah, i was looking for a more playful dramatic tv tone, updated question  @user_A

Comment: yeah, I was trying to find something thats playfully dramatic from a soap opera romantic tv show, feel free to reedit answer as needed

Answer (score 0):

"영원희 안녕" could be a literal translation and I don't think it's weird to say. Probably it could be very attractive and/or famous to say depends on TV show's context and who speaks when/whom under certain situation. In Korean language, "결별" could imply something like "forever goodbye"... but it would sound weird someone say 결별 in the TV show. It's more written language style  I guess?

Comment: yeah, I was trying to find something thats dramatic from a soap opera romantic tv show